# ScalaCheck :: set initial seed for the generator?

Tags: scalacheck

I need to generate like 1000 random strings of certain size, and compute some hashing object out of them. Then I need to take the strings I used to generate the results and run them through another algorithm to verify that the result from the previous step is correct.

Is it possible to receive the "initial" state of the generator and re-run the generation with it?

**ScalaCheck 1.13.4**

Comment: It sounds like your describing a single property, so I'm not sure why you'd want to share the generated inputs between properties. Perhaps you could clarify your question by adding some code...